# Querying RDBMS transaction logs live

Tags: database, change-data-capture

This is a Change Data Capture scenario. But instead of enabling CDC on tables, I would like to read the database Transaction logs and filter it for certain tables.

For instance I want to know all updates, deletes, and all DDLs on certain table and then stream that log line into ElasticSearch whenever found.

What are some solutions out there that can let me monitor database logs live and stream to ElasticSearch?

Appreciate any feedback

Comment: What kind of source database do you want to track? Vendor? Version?

Comment: I have MySQL, Sql Server (both on premise and RDS). But I would love to know if there is a tool/approach that can read transaction log  of all popular RDBMSs out there

Answer (score 0):

Each RDBMs has it's own proprietary transaction log format sometimes version dependent. A few are documented, most are not. Some are intuitive, most are not.

There are companies selling CDC tools which know how to interpret those logs and they spend multiple man-years to properly, consistently, interpret the transaction log. Attunity was such company. Their "Replicate" product is now available through Qlik.

For SQLserver you can call FN_DBLOG (for the live log) and FN_DUMP_DBLOG (for the archived logs) to readily get to the RAW transaction row data. Next you'll need to figure out how to interpret that. Google (duck duck go) is your friend.
Start here perhaps: https://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/reading-sql-server-transaction-logs/

You only can do this on your own for a very limited set RDBMS's, and within there of a very limited set of Rows and Column Datatypes. Once you try to make a generic solution it turns into a career!

Good luck!
Hein.